# nonetype error while assigning the dictionary

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to know where i am wrong following code is a part of my entire code and error coming at **fg_color,bg_color**

```
color_icons=(lightdefault_icon,lightplus_theme,dark_theme,red_theme,monokai_theme,nightblue_theme)

color_dict = {
        'Light Default' : ('#000000',"#ffffff"),
        'Light Plus'  : ('#474747','#e0e0e0'),
        'Dark' : ('#c4c4c4','#2d2d2d'),
        'Red'  : ('#2d2d2d','#ffe8e8'),
        'Monokai' : ('#d3b774','#474747'),
        'Night Blue'  : ('#ededed','#6b9dc2')

    }


def color_wheel():
    get_theme = theme_choose.get()
    colour_tuple=color_dict.get(get_theme)
    fg_color,bg_color = colour_tuple[0],colour_tuple[1]
    text_editor.config(background=bg_color, fg=fg_color)

count = 0
for key in color_dict:
    color_theme.add_radiobutton(label=key,image=color_icons[count],compound=tk.LEFT,command=color_wheel)
    count+=1
```

this is my error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jhasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\BE_Project\assets\notepad.py", line 414, in color_wheel
    fg_color,bg_color = colour_tuple[0],colour_tuple[1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: I think `colour_tuple` becomes `None`

Comment: ``color_dict.get(get_theme)`` explicitly asks for the value associated with ``get_theme`` *or ``None`` as a fallback*. What do you *intend* to happen if a theme is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, colour_tuple became `None` because the key does not exist.
To solve this problem, either use a fallback

```
colour_tuple=color_dict.get(get_theme, ('#000000',"#ffffff"))
```

or check for None:

```
if colour_tuple: # using python's implicit boolean conversion
    g_color,bg_color = colour_tuple[0],colour_tuple[1]
    text_editor.config(background=bg_color, fg=fg_color)
```

MisterMiyagi's proposal:

```
try:
    colour_tuple = color_dict[get_theme]
except IndexError:
    return
```

Comment: For the checked case, instead of getting the value *or a default* and checking whether the default was returned, merely getting the value in a ``try:``/``except:`` (where the ``except:`` path aborts) is faster and likely makes the intention clearer.